# Data binding in ionic application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on employeeManagement application, it take care of employee database and some review associated with the employee. I am using ionic storage for local storage purpose and mysql as database.

I have to show some data on a page as soon as page loads...but page is getting load earlier than object gets it value from the database.

below is the code

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of reviews"  >
   {{ item.remarks }}
</ion-list>
```

And .ts file is as below:

```
export class EmpDetailPage {
  data : EmployeeDetail[] ;
  emp_id: number;
  data_emp:EmployeeDetail;
  emp_name:string='';
  behaviour:number;
  socialism:number;
  communication:number;
  technical:number;
  management:number;
  reviews: ReviewMap[]=[];
  feedback : ReviewMap;
  remarks:string='';
  rating :number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public storage: Storage) {
      this.emp_id=navParams.get("emp_id");
      this.emp_name=navParams.get("emp_name");
      this.data=[];

      this.storage.get('EmpReviews').then((data)=>{

      //let ionic_review=data;
      this.reviews=data;
   })


}
```

I have populated the values of reviews in constructor itself but it is not getting displayed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you sure the data you receive from the storage is an array as expected?

Comment: yeah data is correct and same as what I expected, and also there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You had stored array of data, I think you should use looping statement to access those data, and make sure data loading using console.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have done with your suggestion, but no improvement